# Get relative vector3 of docked ship on mothership

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I am using Unity's Vector3d/Quaternion API to try and get the relative vector3 with two absolute vectors. I have a mothership and its absolute position, and I have the absolute position of a vehicle docked on said mothership. I want to get a vector that stays the same no matter the rotation and position of the mothership, given the docked vehicle stays in place on the ship. The position part is easy (just subtracting the vectors) but I cannot figure out how to manage the rotation. How can I do this?

Comment: Are these Rigidbody? Otherwise what speaks against parenting? Or against having a dedicated child dockingPoint and copy its position and rotation?

Comment: By the way, your title is misleading because the title sounds like it's talking about relative positioning but the body of the question asks about relative rotations.

Comment: @Ruzihm yup got me also in the first moment ^^

Answer (score 1):

Using some quaternion algebra:

```
StartingMothershipRot * relativeRot = StartingDockedShipRot
```

such that you can calculate the docked ship rotation later:

```
LaterMothershipRot * relativeRot = LaterDockedShiprot
```

multiply by `Inverse(StartingMothershipRot)` on left sides:

```
relativeRot = Inverse(StartingMothershipRot) * StartingDockedShipRot
```

Expressing in Unity code (putting with simple example of position code):

```
// Vector3 relativePos; (e.g.)
Quaternion relativeRot;

Transform mothership;
Transform dockedShip;

// ...

// ... when docking occurs
// relativePos = mothership.InverseTransformPoint(dockedShip.position); (e.g.)
relativeRot = Quaternion.Inverse(mothership.rotation) * dockedShip.rotation;


// ...

// ... on each frame update, move docked ship to correct pos & rotation
// dockedShip.position = mothership.TransformPoint(relativePos);  (e.g.)
dockedShip.rotation = mothership.rotation * relativeRot;
```